# Found too many current_mirror incs!

Tags: rdiff-backup

After upgrading my rdiff backup

```
rdiff-backup --version
rdiff-backup 1.2.8
```

i get the following error message:

```
Exception 'Found too many current_mirror incs!' raised of class '<type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>':
```

**How would i find out which directory is having the issue?**

Answer (score 1):

I filed a bug report https://github.com/sol1/rdiff-backup/issues/37 and found the following work-around. It finds directories with multiple current_mirror entries. The ones with more than two are the culprit.

In my case two of the three files had a similar timestamp and I removed the one that was one minute older - now the error is gone.

**Example:**

```
doe@computer:/backup/rbackup$ sudo ./countmirror 
      3 ./company/Admin/rdiff-backup-data
```

**Script:**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157138/recursively-counting-files-in-a-linux-directory

#
# get the current mirrors
# param 1: filter
#
get_current_mirrors() {
  local l_filter="$1"
  for f in $(find . -name current_m* ) ; do 
    d=$(dirname $f)
    b=$(basename $f)
    case $l_filter in
      "dir") echo $d;;
      "file") echo $f;;
      *) echo $f
    esac
  done
}

#get_current_mirrors 
#get_current_mirrors file
get_current_mirrors dir | sort | uniq --count --repeated
```